# Need to create a Pandas dataframe by reading csv file with random columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have the following csv file with records:

- A 1, B 2, C 10, D 15
- A 5, D 10, G 2
- D 6, E 7
- H 7, G 8

My column headers/names are:  A, B, C, D, E, F, G

So my initial dataframe after using "read_csv" becomes:

```
A     B     C      D       E      F      G   
A 1   B 2   C 10   D 15   NaN    NaN    NaN
A 5   D 10  G 2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
D 6   E 7   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
H 7   G 8   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    Nan
```

The value can be separate into [column name][column value], so A 1 means col=A and value=1, and D 15 means col=D and value=15, etc...

What I want is to assign the numeric value to the appropriate column based on the 
and have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A     B     C      D       E      F      G   
A 1   B 2   C 10   D 15   NaN    NaN    NaN
A 5   Nan   NaN    D 10   NaN    NaN    G 2
NaN   NaN   NaN    D 6    E 7    NaN    NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    G 8
```

And even better, just the values alone:

```
A     B     C      D       E      F      G   
1     2     10     15      NaN    NaN    NaN
5     Nan   NaN    10      NaN    NaN    2
NaN   NaN   NaN    6       7      NaN    NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN    8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through rows with `apply` function(`axis = 1`) and construct a pandas series for each row based on the key value pairs after the splitting, and the newly constructed series will be automatically aligned by their index, just notice here there is no `F` column but an extra `H`, not sure if it is what you need. But removing the `H` and adding an extra NaN `F` column should be straight forward:

```
df.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({x[0]: x[1] for x in r.str.split(' ') 
                                    if isinstance(x, list) and len(x) == 2}), axis = 1)


#     A   B   C   D   E   G   H
#0    1   2  10  15 NaN NaN NaN
#1    5 NaN NaN  10 NaN   2 NaN
#2  NaN NaN NaN   6   7 NaN NaN
#3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   8   7
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my dataframe.  It gives me IndexError: ('list index out of range', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Several things I can think of, when you read the data in, there might be leading or trailing spaces for each string; And each string may not be separated by one space and there might be multiple instead of paired values for each cell.

Comment: Blame the nan cells, @Psidom. OP is getting a list index out of range, because nan will not resolve into a list under `.str.split`. So you cannot index into it (where you so cleverly write `x[0] : x[1]`). I also never knew that list comprehension like syntax works inside curly braces. Thank you for that enlightenment!

Answer (score 2):

**Apply** solution:

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by whitespace, remove `NaN` rows by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and convert one column `DataFrame` to `Series` by [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html). Last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by new column names:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(expand=True)
                               .dropna()
                               .set_index(0)
                               .squeeze(), axis=1)
         .reindex(columns=list('ABCDEFGH')))

     A    B    C    D    E   F    G    H
0    1    2   10   15  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
1    5  NaN  NaN   10  NaN NaN    2  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN    6    7 NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN    8    7
```

**Stack** solution:

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for creating `Series`, [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by whitespace and create new columns, append column with new column names (`A`, `B`...) to `index` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), convert one column `DataFrame` to `Series` by [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html), remove index values with old column names by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by new column names (it add missing columns filled by `NaN`),convert values to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and last remove column name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df.stack()
         .str.split(expand=True)
         .set_index(0, append=True)
         .squeeze()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .unstack()
         .reindex(columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
         .astype(float)
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

     A    B     C     D    E   F    G    H
0  1.0  2.0  10.0  15.0  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
1  5.0  NaN   NaN  10.0  NaN NaN  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN   NaN   6.0  7.0 NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN NaN  8.0  7.0
```

Comment: Good solution! All in one line as we love it! +1... Also, I didn't know about the `expand` kwag in `.str.split`, that will save a line off my solution, and also an operation potentially making it faster...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))

def classifier(row):
    cols = row.str.split().str[0].dropna().tolist()
    vals = row.str.split().str[1].dropna().tolist()
    res.loc[row.name, cols] = vals

df.apply(classifier, axis=1)
```

---

Input:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = """A 1, B 2, C 10, D 15
A 5, D 10, G 2
D 6, E 7
H 7, G 8"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)
print("df:\n", df)

res = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))

def classifier(row):
    cols = row.str.split().str[0].dropna().tolist()
    vals = row.str.split().str[1].dropna().tolist()
    res.loc[row.name, cols] = vals
df.apply(classifier, axis=1)

print("\nres:\n", res)
```

Output:

```
df:
    0    1     2     3
0   A 1  B 2   C 10  D 15
1   A 5  D 10  G 2   NaN
2   D 6  E 7   NaN   NaN
3   H 7  G 8   NaN   NaN

res:
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
0   1   2   10  15  NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   5   NaN NaN 10  NaN NaN 2   NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN 6   7   NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 8   7
```