# Sorting and arranging a list using pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, split

I have an input file as shown below which needs to be arranged in such an order that the key values need to be in ascending order, while the keys which are not present need to be printed in the last. 
I am getting the data arranged in the required format but the order is missing.

I have tried using sort() method but it shows "list has no attribute sort".
Please suggest solution and also suggest if any modifications required.

Input file:

```
3=1388|4=1388|5=IBM|8=157.75|9=88929|1021=1500|854=n|388=157.75|394=157.75|474=157.75|1584=88929|444=20160713|459=93000546718000|461=7|55=93000552181000|22=89020|400=157.75|361=0.73|981=0|16=1468416600.6006|18=1468416600.6006|362=0.46
3=1388|4=1388|5=IBM|8=157.73|9=100|1021=0|854=p|394=157.73|474=157.749977558|1584=89029|444=20160713|459=93001362639104|461=26142|55=93001362849000|22=89120|361=0.71|981=0|16=1468416601.372|18=1468416601.372|362=0.45
3=1388|4=1388|5=IBM|8=157.69|9=100|1021=600|854=p|394=157.69|474=157.749910415|1584=89129|444=20160713|459=93004178882560|461=27052|55=93004179085000|22=89328|361=0.67|981=1|16=1468416604.1916|18=1468416604.1916|362=0.43
```

Code i tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('inputfile', index_col=None, names=['text'])
s = df.text.str.split('|')
ds = [dict(w.split('=', 1) for w in x) for x in s]
p = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ds)
p1 = p.replace(np.nan,'n/a', regex=True)
st = p1.stack(level=0,dropna=False)
dfs = [g for i,g in st.groupby(level=0)]
#print st
i = 0
while i < len(dfs):    
    #index of each column
    print ('\nindex[%d]'%i)
    for (_,k),v in dfs[i].iteritems():
        print k,'\t',v
    i = i + 1
```

output getting:

```
index[0]
1021  1500
1584  88929
16    1468416600.6006
18    1468416600.6006
22    89020
3     1388
361   0.73
362   0.46
388   157.75
394   157.75
4     1388
400   157.75
444   20160713
459   93000546718000
461   7
474   157.75
5     IBM
55    93000552181000
8     157.75
854   n
9     88929
981   0

index[1]
1021  0
1584  89029
16    1468416601.372
18    1468416601.372
22    89120
3     1388
361   0.71
362   0.45
388   n/a
394   157.73
4     1388
400   n/a
444   20160713
459   93001362639104
461   26142
474   157.749977558
5     IBM
55    93001362849000
8     157.73
854   p
9     100
981   0
```

Expected output:

```
index[0]
3     1388
4     1388
5     IBM
8     157.75
9     88929
16    1468416600.6006
18    1468416600.6006
22    89020
55    93000552181000
361   0.73
362   0.46
388   157.75
394   157.75
400   157.75
444   20160713
459   93000546718000
461   7
474   157.75
854   n
981   0
1021  1500
1584  88929

index[1]
3     1388
4     1388
5     IBM
8     157.75
9     88929
16    1468416600.6006
18    1468416600.6006
22    89020
55    93000552181000
361   0.73
362   0.46
394   157.75
444   20160713
459   93000546718000
461   7
474   157.75
854   n
981   0
1021  1500
1584  88929
388   n/a
400   n/a
```

Comment: It looks like you're inputting as string and sorting that. If you convert the tag number to integer before storing you should get the sorted output you expect.

Comment: I think you should answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39648855/3765319)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your ds line with

```
ds = [{int(pair[0]): pair[1] for pair in [w.split('=', 1) for w in x]} for x in s]
```

To convert the index to an integer so it will be sorted numerically

To output the n/a values at the end, you could use the pandas selection to output the nonnull values first, then the null values, e.g:

```
for (ix, series) in p.iterrows():
    print('\nindex[%d]' % ix)
    output_series(ix, series[pd.notnull])
    output_series(ix, series[pd.isnull].fillna('n/a'))
```

btw, you can also simplify your stack, groupby, print to:

```
for (ix, series) in p1.iterrows():
    print('\nindex[%d]' % ix)
    for tag, value in series.iteritems():
        print(tag, '\t', value)
```

So the whole script becomes:

```
def output_series(ix, series):
    for tag, value in series.iteritems():
        print(tag, '\t', value)

df = pd.read_csv('inputfile', index_col=None, names=['text'])
s = df.text.str.split('|')
ds = [{int(pair[0]): pair[1] for pair in [w.split('=', 1) for w in x]} for x in s]
p = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ds)
for (ix, series) in p.iterrows():
    print('\nindex[%d]' % ix)
    output_series(ix, series[pd.notnull])
    output_series(ix, series[pd.isnull].fillna('n/a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('inputfile', index_col=None, names=['text'])
s = df.text.str.split('|')
ds = [dict(w.split('=', 1) for w in x) for x in s]
p1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ds).fillna('n/a')
st = p1.stack(level=0,dropna=False)
for k, v in st.groupby(level=0):
    print(k, v.sort_index())
```